What happens if I buy call options with a strike price lower than current market value?
Looking into options trading for the very first time and I wanted to make sure I'm understanding things correctly. In my investment app I see call options available for lower than the market value of the stock. Does that mean as soon as I buy, the strike price is met and I could immediately exercise the contract? (I know I wouldn't want to since the break even price would be higher if the seller knows how to charge premiums)

(I know I wouldn't want to since the break even price would be higher if the seller knows how to charge premiums) - you seem to have answered your own question


Does that mean as soon as I buy, the strike price is met and I could immediately exercise the contract?

Technically yes, but you will have lost money.

(I know I wouldn't want to since the break even price would be higher if the seller knows how to charge premiums)

You are not negotiating the price with one seller that might misprice the option. You are participating in an auction with many sellers. There are enough sellers that know how to set the price that you will not find any "easy money" options.  If you find an option that's $20 in the money (e.g. an $80 call on a $100 stock), that option will cost you at least $20. There is no free lunch.
Also for this reason, it's almost always better to sell the option rather than exercising early - you'll get more money from selling the option that you will have saved by exercising it.

Owners of options have the right to exercise them.
If an option still has time value, it's better to sell to close rather than exercising because exercising throws away the time premium.
In-the-money options often trade below intrinsic value, particularly near expiration. Suppose it's a call.  This means that you would not be able to sell your call for its full value. You could attempt price improvement but there's little incentive for anyone to give you intrinsic value, particularly with illiquid options. And while waiting for the trade to fill, the price of the underlying could drop and you'd lose some of your gain.
To avoid this haircut, do a discount arbitrage. Short the stock and then immediately exercise your call to acquire the stock, netting the difference.  Shorting the stock first avoids leg out risk. If you owned discounted puts, you'd buy the stock first.
